# How to create a glitch free stroke icon in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, icon, interface-design

I'm creating an icon but if I use it in small resolution screen it's shown with glitches like follow:[image: This is original image-Glitch Free]

[image: This is Glitched]

Comment: Welcome on GD.SO, PatidarNikunj. When an image is composed by elements with great contrast of color (like in your example), the resampling process introduces a lot of artefacts. Have you ever considered to use a vector program like [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/) or [Adobe illustrator](http://www.adobe.com)? A vector based image maintains a good look even if scaled.

Comment: No not yet Just using Adobe Photoshop to do so. So if I'm gonna use Adobe Illustrator can I get better glitch free image?

Comment: For sure. If you have got a valid license of Adobe Illustrator, I suggest you to use it for similar works (if your license is not valid, use an open source alternative). Read also [here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/260/what-are-the-differences-between-vector-graphics-and-raster-graphics), [here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/17311/which-is-better-for-icon-design-vector-graphics-or-raster-graphics), and also [here](http://www.prepressure.com/library/file-formats/bitmap-versus-vector). Please, update us on your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert you icon to smart object first and then scale it.

[image]